# Hide Magento Regular Price if tiered pricing exists on product page

Tags: magento

I am trying to figure out how to hide the regular price on a product page only if tiered pricing exists for the product.  Any tips would be gratefully appreciated.

I have been working on the following code to conditionally display price if tiered pricing but just cannot get it to work.

`<?php if (count($_tierPrices) == 0): ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Sorry, I probably did not make myself that clear.  I wish to hide the base price on products with tiered pricing so that only the tiered pricing block shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Tier price is something that is added when a certain quantity of product is selected. So for default product there should not be any tier price. When certain product is selected tier price is added

There is a block which displays tier price if there is any tier price present

Comment: Sorry, I probably did not make myself that clear. I wish to hide the base price on products with tiered pricing so that only the tiered pricing block shows up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have already come across the tutorial in your link and am using this code to display the lowest tiered price for a product.  What it does not solve however is how to remove the base (regular price) for the product page.  Now I could simply comment out '<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>' from catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml but this will remove the price from products that do not have tiered pricing.

Comment: @user2179269. Did you find a good solution for this? I am having the same problem and I don't understand why there aren't many many Magento users out there who have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code with a conditional statement in `catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml`:

```
<?php if (count($_tierPrices) == 0): ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional statement in catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml

```
<?php if (count($this->getTierPrices()) == 0): ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```