# Magento special price is showing zero by default

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a site in magento where all product's special prize is showing zero by default, though I didn't set any special price for products.

for example,it showing->

Regular Price: $755.00

Special Price: $0.00

how to hide those special prices and make visible only for those products where special price is applicable? otherwise the default price should be shown.

Comment: On your CMS go to the product and remove whatever value is in the special price field. If you don't want to show it on the frontend keep the value empty.

Comment: @medina : i didn't put any value in special price field, I already kept it blank. I only put value in regular price field.But still it showing Regular Price: $466.00 and Special Price: $0.00. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I have just checked on my local Magento installation if i add 0 in special prices while editing a product and do not even select a date, it start showing on the frontend as in your case.

[image]

So i bet you need to remove all special prices which must be set as 0 from admin panel by editing all products showing this behavior.

Also try to clear all cache, and index site.

Comment: I checked my admin panel, and found out I didn't put special price value=0 even also i didn't set any date.now the most interesting thing is if I put some value in special price field and select a valid date, the result is showing same as you mentioned image...pleas help.

Comment: have you recently installed any extension on the site ?

Comment: yes 'related product manager' for related product. Interestingly, in localhost i have not facing this problem.

Comment: try disabling it from app/etc/module your plugin file set active true to false

Comment: i have tried it and also uninstalled it...but its not working.

Comment: last thing go to templates/catalog/product/price.phtml and try to debug the if else used to display special price, once you find which condition is fullfilling and can reach to the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

You may get solution for your question in magento forum.

Please check below link:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/76338/

You may refer SO Link also:

[Hide Magento Regular Price if tiered pricing exists on product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135393/hide-magento-regular-price-if-tiered-pricing-exists-on-product-page)